# While loop not terminating properly

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

So I've got this code, it guesses a number between 0 and 100. 
It prompts a number and the user answers with 'h' 'l' or 'c'

now everything works fine except that I want this line to only show when the user input is not equal to 'h', 'l' or 'c' instead now it shows up even if I enter 'c' which would break the loop, right?

```
print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."
```

full code

```
start = 0
end = 100
guess = int((start+end)/2.0)
print "Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
print


x= 'n'

while x != 'c':

    print 'Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + '?'
    x = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.").lower()
    if x == 'h':
        end = guess
    elif x == 'l':
        start = guess
    else: 
        print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."
guess = int((start + end)/2)

print 'your answer is: ' + str(guess)
```

So to clarify this is the output even when I enter 'c'

```
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess     is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.c

Sorry, I did not understand your input.
```

your answer is: 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an `elif` for the `'c'` case, so it falls to the final `else`.

Add, the following to handle that case and break the while loop:

```
elif x == 'c':
    break
```

In addition, you can just do `while True:` and loop until `c` breaks.

Your higher/lower logic is backward as well.  for `h`, start = guess, for example.

The update to `guess` should be indented inside the while loop.

Comment: Thank you ! Now I finally understand what that break is used for , I was confused. 

Now I can finally continue with my course. Much love !